# Problema en programa recursivo

Tags: c++

el siguiente programa que dada una secuencia de strings, imprime la mitad de los insertados pero en orden inverso, no funciona. Estoy intentando hacerlo con recursividad.
Un ejemplo de buen funcionamiento sería:

Input:

> dolphins
> octopuses
> squid
> sharks
> whales
> piranhas

Output:

> squid
> octopuses
> dolphins

y en cambio no da salida.

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printline(int& n){
    string s;
    int ntemp;
    if (cin >> s) {
        ++n;
        printline(n);
        ntemp = n;
    }
    if (ntemp <= n/2) cout << s;
    else --ntemp;
}

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    printline(n);
}
```

Comment: Solo te falla la asignación `ntemp = n`, que la haces a destiempo. Elimina esa línea y hazlo directamente al crear la variable: `int ntemp = n;`

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que lo mejor es primero leer los strings y luego imprimirlos al revés.

Así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str;
    vector<string> sequence;

    while (cin >> str){
        sequence.push_back(str);
    }

    for (int i = sequence.size() / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        cout << sequence[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##TY/BbsIwDIbveQqLXcKhY9u1JS@CJpSlHrVokxAnm7SJZ@8cCoNcLP@//y@2i7E5ODfPT@TdWHqEjgLnhHYy6q6JQv7wqHyhyyEZpQqLA95OyNE6BM59qxT5DJMlr9e/CuQtgFraS7/Eb1xgPBX0DiVZ3e@BRgTtyIMxNXSlXEjX0edYeNh/WHfUdWDBnpf8Z0ig6woE23uA6Qf1GjbwBg28tmKaLbxIbZoHvgslQ9f9x3b0XtsVrG5fnOe5D2McyDMEOUMWQQY@FeqBB5uOLAfYUbRIyfrB8h8).